# How to get client IP address if it is routed by ARR

Tags: c#, .net, iis, arr

The IP on the service machine that is logged is IP of ARR server machine, not of the end client.
How to get the actual client IP on the end server doing the work?

Answer (score 4):

The **X-Forwarded-For** (XFF) HTTP header field is a de facto standard for identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer.

This setting should be configurable based on what type of proxy or loadbalancer you are using. Thus, you can determine the client IP by inspecting the HTTP header on the server. Check the ARR config if use x-forwarded-for is enabled.

There are also options in IIS to log the client IP address if XFF is utilized.